# Typescript does not grab custom types from the referenced project

Tags: typescript, ts-node

My project structure is next (I'm running code with `ts-node`)

```
project-a
    tsconfig.json // referencing 'common'
    specs/
        test.ts // import 'helper.js' from "../../common/utils/helper.js"

project-b
    tsconfig.json // has my own custom types in the 'types'
    lib-types/
        global/
            index.d.ts // defenition what is 'foo' is here
    utils/
        helper.js // this file has global var 'foo' in it
```

**utils.js** (project-b)

```
global.foo = 'Hello!'

function helper() {
    return foo
}

module.exports = {helper}
```

**test.ts** (project-a)

```
import {helper} from "../../common/utils/helper"
import {assert} from 'chai'

describe('Test block', ()=> {
    it('Test', ()=> {        
        assert.strictEqual(helper(), 'Hello!', 'Should greet')
    })
})
```

Thanks to  `"types": ["./lib-types/global"]` in the **project-b** `tsconfig.json` TS is aware of what `foo` and is working fine inside **project-b** folder.

But when I try to reference **proejct-a** to **project-b**, first project throws an error:

```
TSError: » Unable to compile TypeScript:
../common/utils/helper.js(1,8): error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.
../common/utils/helper.js(4,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'foo'.
```

Configs:

**project-a tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "strict": false,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "types": ["mocha", "node", "chai"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
        "specs/**/*"
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../common",
        }
    ]
}
```

**project-b tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "strict": false,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "types": [
            "node", 
            "./lib-types/global"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        // composite options
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true
    },
    "include": ["utils/**/*"]
}
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong while referencing projects.

Or I just didn't got the idea of the reference right...

Is it possible to make **project-a** be aware of the own custom types of **project-b** WITHOUT explicitly specifying the `"../common/types/global"` in **project-a** folder?

p.s. I'm aware of `extends` and shared configs but this is not a case for me

UPD:

Not sure is this important but here is how tests are run:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha './specs/**/*.test.js' './specs/**/*.test.ts' --file ./ts.runner.js"
  },
```

**ts.runner.js**

```
require("ts-node").register({ files: true })
```

Comment: When referencing, the tsconfig doesn't import settings from the other tsconfig, so it doesn't pick up the `types` property. References will cause the project to reference declaration or `.d.ts` files, but you're not generating one of those for utils.js. You could try referencing `lib-types/global` in project-a's `types`, or just importing it directly in some other declaration file in project-a.

Comment: So I got the idea wrong... Is there any way I can "pull" types from another tsconfig? (`extends` work in runtime, but VScode does not grab the "alien" types during development)